# When I try to run MPI code, I get undefined reference to MPI_File_Seek@12, What might be the reason?

Tags: c, mpi

I've been trying to run the code from https://github.com/dungtn/mpi-floyd/blob/master/floyd2d.c in my system. I'm using CodeBlocks IDE and MS-Mpi. When I try to compile the code, it says undefined reference to MPI_file_seek@12. Does this mean MS mpi does not support this function or why does this happen?

Comment: `MPI_file_seek@12` is not a valid C function name. Did you perhaps compile as C++? The typical name mangling there looks like that.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig, the name of the function is `MPI_File_seek`. `@12` is the `stdcall` name decoration.

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens if you are trying to link 32-bit code with 64-bit libraries. The fact that the unresolved symbol has `@12` in its name means that the compiler is expecting that `MPI_File_seek` is an **stdcall** function. **stdcall** is mainly used for DLL functions and only on x86 (x64 uses a different calling convention similar to **fastcall**). If you are linking against the 64-bit import library of MS-MPI, the decorated symbol won't be found in the library and such an error will occur.

Double check what version of MS-MPI you have and also your project settings and make sure that both have the same "bitness".

Answer (score 1):

Change the project settings in Code::Blocks to a C project (rather than C++ project, what you have currently). It may be easier to create a brand new C project and import the file there. Double check that Code::Blocks in running `gcc` and not `g++` to compile your code (`floyd2d.c`).

If it still doesn't work, please post the full compiler and linker output of Code::Blocks, including the commands run and their output messages.

Comment: For MPI, you probably want `mpicc`, not `gcc`.

Comment: @WesleyBland, MS-MPI does not provide compiler wrappers.

Comment: `g++` treats files with names that end in `.c` as C and not as C++ files.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Incorrect. Correctly: `g++` treats files with names that end in `.c` as C++ files.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. It's the generic `gcc` command that invokes the correct frontend based on the file extension. `g++` does the same but only when given the `-x none` option.